# Unable to click or select the value which is displayed in dropdown

Tags: java, ajax, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to implement some code using Selenium Webdriver using Java.

Basically, I have a website with a text box. Once user enter the first letter, based on that a value will be displayed(using AJAX). I need to select the particular value, which i mentioned in send keys .

```
WebElement fromCity = driver.findElement(By.id("pickUpLocation"));
fromCity.sendKeys("A Ma Temple / 媽閣");

Thread.sleep(2000);

WebElement ajaxContainer1 = driver.findElement(By.className("txt-box ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid"));
WebElement ajaxHolder1 = ajaxContainer1.findElement(By.tagName("ul"));
List<WebElement> ajaxValues1 = ajaxHolder1.findElements(By.tagName("li"));

for (WebElement value1 : ajaxValues1) {
    if (value1.getText().equals("A Ma Temple ")) {
        ((WebElement)ajaxValues1).click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: So where are you stuck? Are you seeing any error? At which line? What does the error says? Update the question with complete error stack trace and relevant HTML.

Comment: i cannot able to click or select the value which is displayed in dropdown

Comment: Change `((WebElement)ajaxValues1).click();` to `value1.click();`

Comment: i did the same, but still same issue persist

Answer (score 0):

After you send keys.your Ajax value should be retrieved in a box related to you keyword search.You need to get the complete box.and fetch each one as you have done in for loop .get the text and compare it with your expected text and click where this condition is true.
What is that line for before thread.sleep()

Answer (score 0):

I think u can try selecting through index. It should be like this

```
List<WebElement> ajaxValues1 = ajaxHolder1.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
Select dropdown= new Select(ajaxValues1);
dropdown.selectByIndex(0);
dropdown.selectByIndex(1);
dropdown.selectByIndex(2);
```

0 represents the first element in the dropdown. Based on index number of that element, feed the corresponding number in selectByIndex(0)

Let me know if this helps. Thanks

Comment: sorry, still i cannot able to make it